# Coded UI Testing works for everything except Extended.Wpf.Toolkit controls which hides the AutomationID

Tags: wpf, coded-ui-tests

I am using Coded UI Testing (available in Microsoft Visual Studio 2015 Enterprise) and creating tests using the recorder. My tests work perfectly for my WPF application except where I have used "IntegerUpDown" control from the Extended.Wpf.Toolkit controls.

The normal approach when you encounter such a problem is to add the optional property AutomationId in your control in XAML. Then next time you record a test it uses that ID, thus uniquely identifying your XAML control. So for example, my button ...

```
<Button Width="75" Height="40">Click Me</Button>
```

Simply becomes...

```
<Button Width="75" Height="40" AutomationProperties.AutomationId="Btn1">Click Me</Button>
```

And my IntegerUpDown control ...

```
<xctk:IntegerUpDown/>
```

becomes ...

```
<xctk:IntegerUpDown AutomationProperties.AutomationId="Nuid1" />
```

This is easy and works for all controls like buttons etc but not for the IntegerUpDown control that I have used. In the case of the IntegerUpDown, the CodedUI test sees the AutomationID of "AutoSelectTextBox" and not the value "Nuid1" that I have set. Where did this "AutoSelectTextBox" come from and why can I not set the AutomationID in the way that I do for standard WPF controls?

The problem with not being able to set the AutomationID is that recorded tests sometimes cannot tell which control is which. To clarify, I can see the AutomationID when I record a coded ui test by dragging from the target button on the Coded UI Test Builder when recording and I can also see it in the search properties below ...

```
this.mUIAutoSelectTextBoxEdit.SearchProperties[WpfEdit.PropertyNames.AutomationId] = "AutoSelectTextBox";
```

The issue is that "AutoSelectTextBox" is not what I entered, I entered "Nuid1" so why has it been changed in the Extended.Wpf.Toolkit control? In my example above the button's AutomationId="Btn1" does not get changed anywhere, it works fine so I suspect the toolkit is doing something.

Is there a solution to this to get my coded ui tests working?

Just in case it helps, here is the XAML for the window I am testing

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.ControlsWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication1"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="ControlsWindow" Height="900" Width="300"
    WindowStartupLocation="Manual"
    xmlns:xctk="http://schemas.xceed.com/wpf/xaml/toolkit">
<StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
    <Button Width="75" Height="40"
        Canvas.Top="0" Canvas.Left="0" AutomationProperties.AutomationId="Btn1">Click Me</Button>
    <Button Width="75" Height="40"
        Canvas.Top="0" Canvas.Left="0" AutomationProperties.AutomationId="Btn2">Click Me</Button>
    <Button Width="75" Height="40"
        Canvas.Top="0" Canvas.Left="0" AutomationProperties.AutomationId="Btn3">Click Me</Button>
    <Button Width="75" Height="40"
        Canvas.Top="0" Canvas.Left="0" AutomationProperties.AutomationId="Btn4">Click Me</Button>

    <ToggleButton Foreground="White" Background="Red"
        Canvas.Top="40" Canvas.Left="0" AutomationProperties.AutomationId="Tgl1">Toggle Me</ToggleButton>
    <ToggleButton Foreground="White" Background="Red"
        Canvas.Top="40" Canvas.Left="0" AutomationProperties.AutomationId="Tgl2">Toggle Me</ToggleButton>
    <ToggleButton Foreground="White" Background="Red"
        Canvas.Top="40" Canvas.Left="0" AutomationProperties.AutomationId="Tgl3">Toggle Me</ToggleButton>
    <ToggleButton Foreground="White" Background="Red"
        Canvas.Top="40" Canvas.Left="0" AutomationProperties.AutomationId="Tgl4">Toggle Me</ToggleButton>

    <CheckBox BorderBrush="Green" BorderThickness="10"
        Canvas.Top="80" Canvas.Left="0" AutomationProperties.AutomationId="Chk1">Check Me</CheckBox>
    <RadioButton FontFamily="Algerian" FontSize="24"
        Canvas.Top="0" Canvas.Left="80" AutomationProperties.AutomationId="Rad1">Yes</RadioButton>
    <RadioButton FontStyle="Italic" FontWeight="Bold"
        Canvas.Top="50" Canvas.Left="80" AutomationProperties.AutomationId="Rad2">No</RadioButton>
    <CheckBox BorderBrush="Green" BorderThickness="10"
        Canvas.Top="80" Canvas.Left="0" AutomationProperties.AutomationId="Chk2">Check Me</CheckBox>
    <RadioButton FontFamily="Algerian" FontSize="24"
        Canvas.Top="0" Canvas.Left="80" AutomationProperties.AutomationId="Rad3">Yes</RadioButton>
    <RadioButton FontStyle="Italic" FontWeight="Bold"
        Canvas.Top="50" Canvas.Left="80" AutomationProperties.AutomationId="Rad4">No</RadioButton>
    <CheckBox BorderBrush="Green" BorderThickness="10"
        Canvas.Top="80" Canvas.Left="0" AutomationProperties.AutomationId="Chk3">Check Me</CheckBox>
    <RadioButton FontFamily="Algerian" FontSize="24"
        Canvas.Top="0" Canvas.Left="80" AutomationProperties.AutomationId="Rad5">Yes</RadioButton>
    <RadioButton FontStyle="Italic" FontWeight="Bold"
        Canvas.Top="50" Canvas.Left="80" AutomationProperties.AutomationId="Rad6">No</RadioButton>
    <CheckBox BorderBrush="Green" BorderThickness="10"
        Canvas.Top="80" Canvas.Left="0" AutomationProperties.AutomationId="Chk4">Check Me</CheckBox>
    <RadioButton FontFamily="Algerian" FontSize="24"
        Canvas.Top="0" Canvas.Left="80" AutomationProperties.AutomationId="Rad7">Yes</RadioButton>
    <RadioButton FontStyle="Italic" FontWeight="Bold"
        Canvas.Top="50" Canvas.Left="80" AutomationProperties.AutomationId="Rad8">No</RadioButton>

    <xctk:IntegerUpDown AutomationProperties.AutomationId="Nuid1" />
    <xctk:IntegerUpDown AutomationProperties.AutomationId="Nuid2" />
    <xctk:IntegerUpDown AutomationProperties.AutomationId="Nuid3" />
    <xctk:IntegerUpDown AutomationProperties.AutomationId="Nuid4" />        

</StackPanel>
```

Comment: Just to add, the Extended.Wpf.Toolkit is available using NuGet and there's help from the vendor in what references to add etc to get it working. Mine does work, it's just not testable when my layout get complicate and I need to use the AutomationId.

Comment: I have the same issue, the best I've managed to do so far is to add a line: `<UserControl Name="Nuid1Locator" Visibility="Collapsed" />` before each  xctk element. Then the actual element can be resolved as the next sibling using this ugly but functional line: `var nuid1 = nuid1Locator
.FindFirst(TreeScope.Parent, Condition.TrueCondition)
.FindAll(TreeScope.Children, Condition.TrueCondition)
.Cast<AutomationElement>()
.SkipWhile(element => !element.Equals(nuid1Locator))
.First(element => element.Current.AutomationId.Equals("AutoSelectTextBox"));`.

Comment: Found an issue ticket for this, it's over 2 years old though. :( http://wpftoolkit.codeplex.com/workitem/19541 Found an explanation: http://wpftoolkit.codeplex.com/discussions/659123

Comment: Faced this issue too and found that it's a feature of their paid Plus version https://github.com/xceedsoftware/wpftoolkit/issues/1441 and here https://github.com/xceedsoftware/wpftoolkit/wiki/Xceed-Toolkit-Plus-for-WPF

Comment: As for the workarounds, I placed the needed element (SplitButton, which has two buttons inside) into a borderless GroupBox, tuned margins, and assigned Id to that group box. Then I locate it and find its children for a needed button or toggle button.

Comment: Thanks folks, I no longer use CodedUI so i can;t check your comments although I'm sure you are correct. , have switched over to Selenium / c#, WinAppDriver and Dev-ops. I believe this has superceded CodedUI, personally I think it's much better than  CodedUI and I'd never go back.